# How to implement a node with an array of pointers?

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

So for my project, I need to make a linked list with nodes that point in 4 different directions. Here is the node declaration:

```
class Node {
public:
    Node(string newname);
    Node();
    void setNodeName(string newname);
    string getNodeName();
    void attachNewNode(Node *newNode, int direction);
    Node *getAttachedNode(int direction);
private:
    string name;
    Node *attachedNodes[4];
};
```

and here is my implementation:

```
Node::Node(string newname) {
    newname = name;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        attachedNodes[i] = NULL;
    }
}

Node::Node() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        attachedNodes[i] = NULL;
    }
}

void Node::setNodeName(string newname) {
    newname = name;
}
string Node::getNodeName() {
    return name;
}
void Node::attachNewNode(Node *newNode, int direction){
    newNode = attachedNodes[direction];
}
Node *getAttachedNode(int direction) {
    return attachedNodes[direction];
}
```

The code getAttachedNode(int direction) method is giving error: "use of undeclared identifier 'attachedNodes'" on the return line. Pointers always mess me up and I'm sure that's the problem. I also am not sure if I have the correct logic for the function implementations. Any syntax errors? Or am I implementing them wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't this `newNode = attachedNodes[direction];` be just the other way round: `attachedNodes[direction] = newNode;`?

Comment: You forgot you class name on the method `getAttachedNode()`, i.e. it should be `Node::getAttachedNode(int direction)`

Answer (score 2):

Just like this:

```
Node* Node::getAttachedNode(int direction) {
    return attachedNodes[direction];
}
```

Like your other methods.

Comment: To be more explicit, the original code lacked the class namespace `Node::` which caused the problem.